# Setting up triple integral, checking if bounds are correct

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate a triple integral to find the voulume of the solid paraboloid $x = 4y^2 + 4 z^2$ and the plane $x = 4$. DO NOT EVALUATE THE INTEGRAL.

Attempted solution - We have $$x = 4 = 4y^2 + 4z^2 \Rightarrow y^2 + z^2 = 1$$ From this we see that $$z = \pm \sqrt{1-y}$$ Thus I believe we have $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y}}^{\sqrt{1-y}}\int_{4y^2 + 4z^2}^{4} dx dz dy$$ But I am not absolutely sure this is correct. Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paraboloid intersect the plane on a circle that has equation $y^2+z^2=1$ , with $x=4$, o the limits for $x$ are $0<x<4$,The limits for $z$are given by the circular sections of the paraboloid:   $-\sqrt{1-y^2}<z<\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and , for real values of $z$, the limits for $y$ are $-1<y<1$.

So the integral is:
$$
\int_0^4 \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dzdydx
$$